# Pass uint8_t array to method

Tags: objective-c, c, uint8t

I have four `uint8_t` arrays:

```
uint8_t arrayOne[12]   = { 0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0xFE,0x03,0x01,0xC1,0x00,0x01 };

uint8_t arrayTwo[12]   = { 0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0xFE,0x03,0x4E,0x2D,0x00,0x0C };

uint8_t arrayThree[12] = { 0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0xFE,0x03,0x01,0xF3,0x00,0x01 };

uint8_t arrayFour[12]  = { 0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0xFE,0x03,0x20,0x04,0x00,0x01 };
```

I have added them to array:

```
uint8_t *theArray[] = { arrayOne,arrayTwo,arrayThree,arrayFour };
```

now I want to pass this array to a method, for example:

```
[self theMethod:theArray];
```

to:

```
-(void)theMethod:(uint8_t *)pointersArray[]{
...
...
}
```

**What is the proper way to point that array to a method in -(void)theMethod... ?**

Comment: "I have added them to array". No you haven't. `uint8_t *theArray = { arrayOne,arrayTwo,arrayThree,arrayFour };` is not valid C and will not compile. Post the actual code you are using.

Comment: It's an Objective-C. And it compiles.

Comment: Ok, removed the C tag for you.

Comment: Valid C is a valid Objective-C. And first part of question is C.

Comment: @Roo `uint8_t *theArray` should be `uint8_t *theArray[]`

Comment: @Roo The first part of the question, including the declaration of `theArray`, is _not_ valid C. What's allowed in Objective-C, I have no idea.

Comment: @Lundin It's not valid in objective-C either, but the compiler lets it slide with the warning *"Excess elements in scalar initializer"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
uint8_t *theArray = { arrayOne,arrayTwo,arrayThree,arrayFour };
```

is actually creating an array filled in with the **pointers to your arrays  converted to uint8_t** values. I don't think this is what you want.

So first of all (notice the double pointer):

```
uint8_t *theArray[] = { arrayOne,arrayTwo,arrayThree,arrayFour };
```

Then your ObjC method becomes:

```
-(void)theMethod:(uint8_t **)pointersArray {

}
```

Comment: And how can I get the "uint8_t arrayOne[12]" in that method then?

Comment: `uint8_t *arrayOne = pointersArray[0];`
And then you can do `arrayOne[11]` or whatever index you need.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your method to take in a pointer to array pointers

```
-(void)theMethod:(uint8_t **)pointersArray{
...
...
}
```

Invoke the method by passing it like this like

```
[self theMethod:&theArray];
```