# How to compare items in a byte array (passed by reference) to integer values

Tags: objective-c, arrays

For one moment I actually thought I understood this whole pointer, referencing and dereferencing thing, but now I'm stumped again.

```
typedef NS_ENUM (uint8_t, ControlCode) {
    CC_NONE = 0x00, 
    CC_START = 0x01,
    CC_END = 0x02,
};

- (void)testReferencingAnArray
{
    uint8_t msgBytes[3];
    msgBytes[0] = CC_START;
    msgBytes[1] = 3;
    msgBytes[2] = CC_END;

    XCTAssertEqual(msgBytes[0], CC_START);//These three tests pass
    XCTAssertEqual(msgBytes[1], 3);
    XCTAssertEqual(msgBytes[2], CC_END);

    uint8_t *msgBytes_pointer = msgBytes;

    [self evaluate:&msgBytes_pointer];
}

- (void)evaluate:(uint8_t **)msgBytes_pointer
{
    XCTAssertEqual(*msgBytes_pointer[0], CC_START); //Test passes
    XCTAssertEqual(*msgBytes_pointer[1], 3); 
        //Test fails with ("<11>") is not equal to ("3") 
    XCTAssertEqual(*msgBytes_pointer[2], CC_END); 
        //Test fails with ("<00>") is not equal to ("<02>") 
}
```

Comment: No need for `(uint8_t **)` when `(uint8_t *)` would suffice, right?

Comment: @FiddlingBits You'd think so, but no, not according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618860/pass-uint8-t-array-to-method.

Comment: I've edited the code to make it clearer that evaluate: expects a pointer to an array. You can pass the array by reference, but then you can't perform comparisons on the items in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to operator precedence,

```
XCTAssertEqual(*msgBytes[0], CC_START);
XCTAssertEqual(*msgBytes[1], 3);
XCTAssertEqual(*msgBytes[2], CC_END);
```

is equivalent to

```
XCTAssertEqual(*(msgBytes[0]), CC_START);
XCTAssertEqual(*(msgBytes[1]), 3);
XCTAssertEqual(*(msgBytes[2]), CC_END);
```

That's not what you want.

What you need is:

```
XCTAssertEqual((*msgBytes)[0], CC_START);
XCTAssertEqual((*msgBytes)[1], 3);
XCTAssertEqual((*msgBytes)[2], CC_END);
```

Comment: And operator precedence means: first dereference and then get the value? Cool. One more thing, in my production code the second test now fails with: ("3") is not equal to ("3") whereby 3 is an NSInteger (32-bit). Any ideas?

Comment: @ElisevanLooij, the array operator `[]` is of higher priority than the pointer dereference operator. I can't explain why the test fails.